# Ancestral state reconstruction, polytomies and the absence of branch lengths

Tags: r, bioinformatics, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I am trying to estimate ancestral states for two binary characters in a full morphology-based phylogenetic tree. I am using `ape::ace` function, `type = "discrete"` and `kappa = 0` as arguments. Unfortunately, I am dealing with two problems about this issue: my topology have three polytomies and tree branches have no lengths.

To perform ancestral state estimation, I firstly used `ape::multi2di` function. However, this procedure creates artificial nodes in the topology. This becomes a new problem, since states at these new nodes are also being estimated.

Is there another way to deal with this situation? There are functions (or packages) other than those of `phytools` that are able to deal with polytomies and the absence of branch lengths in ancestral state reconstruction?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This seems to be more a methodological problem rather than a coding one. You might find more information for your question on the [`ape` mail list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-phylo). Briefly, however, I don't think there's an easy solution. For the non-binary nodes, you can make the topology binary multiple times stochastically (e.g. using `ape::multi2di`) and run your ace on multiple topologies. For the zero branch lengths (which are effectively resolved polytomies) you can artificially increase branch length (e.g. using `dispRity::remove.zero.brlen`).